# Does CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials always return current user's credentials?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# app that is supposed to pass current user's credentials (Domain, Username and Password) to `WebClient`. For some reason the web service returns error 401 - Unauthorized even though I know for a fact, that credential of Window's user that is accessing it are the same as in the web service I'm trying to connect to.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
string jsonbefore = "";
Uri uri = new Uri(ConnectionString);
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=nometadata";

System.IO.Stream response = wc.OpenRead(conn);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
jsonbefore = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Flush();
```

Are there any environment/system settings that are stopping credentials from flowing? I've read up something about `EnvironmentPermission` class, but I don't know whether it's relatable to my problem. 
Are there any better, more consistent ways of passing Windows credentials to a web service? Or is there any way to check if the username, password or domain from `DefaultCredentials` is being passed as null?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/03/using-httpwebrequest-with-credential-manager/

Comment: For windows credentials to work you need the same Group Account on local PC and remote PC.  And user to be put into the group on both PCs.  Usually companies have Group Policy set up so users can send/receive data between PCs.  At home you need to setup Groups.

Comment: Are we talking about a desktop application? For a window service or a web application running on iis, "current" user will likely not be the one you want too use

Comment: So is there a more stable way to pass Windows credentials of current user, as in from code point of view without messing too much in system's settings?

Comment: What exactly is the web service you are trying to access? If it is not in the same domain or not using Windows authentication, the code above simply must fail.